# Cloud Functions for Firebase run at midnight

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

One sort of trigger I can't seem to find with these new Firebase Functions is a function that runs periodically and could do something such as if a data is a certain value, remove it.

I know there is an onwrite function that will do something upon a change, but is there a function that will just loop through a child overall periodically?

Comment: What does periodically firebase functions do? 
I also want to make an autorun function which gathers data a do some functionality on it.

Answer (score 0):

We do not currently have native Cron type events in Cloud Functions, in the meantime check out how we suggest to achieve this in our [periodic deletion of unused accounts example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron) or our [AppEngine cron example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron) on Github.